# Alternative to (or refinement for) State Pattern suffering from LSP violation

Tags: oop, design-patterns, liskov-substitution-principle, state-pattern

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around state-based functionality for an invoicing system we are currently building. The system will support calculation, manual approval, printing, and archiving of invoices.

At first I thought we should use the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) to model this. An invoice would be the context, which delegates printing, archiving, etc. to its currently assigned state.

But this is obviously a bad idea, because the different states (created, approved, printed, archived) should not support the same operations. E.g., you shouldn't be able to print an invoice, which hasn't been approved before. Throwing exceptions for unsupported operations would be a violation of LSP. I found a general description of this problem [here](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/03/09/state-pattern-misuse/).

Does anybody have an idea, how to implement this appropriately?

---

PS: I'm aware that this might sound like some lame-ass homework assignment, but it's not; I need this for a real world system.

Comment: This is mostly throwing stuff at the wall, but you could pass a strategy object to your state transition methods, with callbacks such as `onSuccess()` and `onFailure()`. This would make it explicit that both are valid outcomes that the developer can't completely prevent and that should be handled. (E.g. either go to the result page or display an error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically creating a workflow of application states, where at each state the available operations on an invoice change. The state pattern doesn't seem appropriate, but you can still use it if you also create some operations like `boolean canPrint()` that would have to be used before calling `print()`. `print()` would have a contract that allows throwing exceptions if `canPrint()` returns `false`. This way, subclasses wouldn't break that contract. Another option is to have a `boolean tryPrint()`, that will only print if it can, and return whether it printed.

But, if the states support mostly non-overlapping operations, then maybe the state pattern is not the solution. Take a step back and look for better ways, without trying to fit a specific pattern to your problem. One way is to create a separate class with the necessary operations for each "state": like `CreatedInvoice`, `ApprovedInvoice`, etc. These classes would only have the operations they support.

Comment: Mind you, this must make it impossible for the state of the object to change between `canPrint()` and `print()`.

Comment: @millimoose: yes, but if it does, no problem, `print()` will throw an exception; and you'll have to fix this concurrency bug.

Comment: @millimoose: I added another option.

Comment: Thanks, Jordao. Sounds very reasonable. I have toyed with the idea of creating several different invoice classes too, but dismissed it, because of the need to change the invoice type upon (some) state transitions. Will give it some more thought. Boolean CanXyz() operations are also an option, but I'll have to take a deeper dive into my requirements to judge, how many state-specific operations there will actually be.

Comment: Due to the workflowy nature of the scenario I might even look into .Net Workflow Foundation. But I'm afraid this will be too much overhead for a seemingly small problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Chain of Responsibility Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) might help you here.

Adding the how part and fixing the link.

There can be Calculator, Approver, Printer and Archiver classes which are handler classes. These can have processRequest() overridden from a parent abstract class. Invoice can be a class which is passed to each handler's processRequest() method. The advantage with using the pattern here is newer handlers can be added dynamically and chain links with sequence of handlers can be changed easily.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the State Pattern is really appropriate to your situation is not certain, but if it's not, Liskov is not the reason.  Throwing some sort of "invalid operation in current state" exception can be defined as possible and valid in the state interface, and then subclasses doing this do not violate LSP.

The classic example used for the State Pattern in the [GoF Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) book is a TCPConnection, which definitely has operations not supported or sensible in all states.  You can't transmit on a closed connection, for example.

Comment: I know the GoF example and I think it shows the problem too (whether it's Liskov in a strict sense or not). Checking whether clients can call an operation based on the contexts's state (or handle those exceptions), defeats the state pattern's purpose from my point of view. It clutters client code with conditional blocks, which might have to be adapted every time state logic is changed.